# Whats the meaning of x and arrow in this expression .subscribe(x=>x);

Tags: angular

```
 return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl, user).subscribe(x=>x);
```

Is this arrow function but arrow function is supposed to be like this `()=>`

```
export class ApiService {
  config = new Configuration();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  registerUser(user: any) { 
   return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl, user).subscribe(x=>x);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`()=>` is non-parameterized arrow function

`x => x` is equivalent to `(x) => x` which takes `x` as parameter and then returns `x` as result

---

Btw, subscription does not return value instead Subscription. When you subscribe you generally need to assign it to another variable or use it inside that subscription.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl, user).subscribe(x=>x);
```

Here Subscribe function is to get the response back from the API to the calling function. 
(X => x).

'x' is the response from the API.(Lets say success or failure)

and you are mapping that to 'X'. (you can console it with the help of X )